# Why we don't use gamma rays, x-rays or ultraviolet to transmit data?

Tags: waves, x-rays, gamma-rays, data

The greater the frequency range of a transmission medium, the greater the number of bits per second it can transmit. In other words, the bigger the bandwidth in hertz available, the bigger the bandwidth in bits per second that can be transmitted.

Given that, why we don't use gamma rays, x-rays or ultraviolet to transmit data instead of e.g. visible(light) in optical fiber or microwaves(cell phones)?

Comment: ...because it's not that easy to generate x-rays? This is a question of engineering practicability, not physics concepts.

Comment: Ultraviolet is used in optical fibre transmissions, especially for HPC interconnects. X and gamma rays are difficult to generate and have associated problems of radiation leakage.

Comment: ... and I don't know how to modulate gamma rays at 10 GHz, but there may be a way, I suppose.

Comment: I don't know about mainstream physics, but in medical physics (i.e., radiation oncology), "gamma ray" and "X-ray" are not the names of different energy bands, but rather, the names of photons emitted by different processes.  "Gamma ray" refers to photons that are emitted by nuclear processes, while "X-ray" refers to photons that originate in electronic processes.  There are medical X-ray machines that produce photons with energies that are an order of magnitude higher than any naturally occurring gamma ray.

Comment: Current worries about cell phones causing cancer seem overblown, but if they start outputting gamma rays, that's not something you want to hold next to your head.

Comment: @jameslarge There are a lot of people who are pretty strongly opposed to that convention (which has solid historical roots) because "photons don't come taged with the process that made them". Of course conventions derive their utility from agreement on their meaning so individual communities can get on quite happily despite grumblers elsewhere. In nuclear and particle physics people tend to follow the source convention when talking about processes that make photons, but the energy convention elsewhere.

Comment: @dmckee, That makes a lot of sense.  Medical "physicists" don't get paid to advance our knowledge of the nature of matter and energy.  At the same time, they are deeply interested in knowing every detail of the radiation _sources_ that they use to treat patients.

Answer (score 10):

For data transmission through optical fibers, what you have to worry about is finding the correct material for transmitting the light over long distances.  Consider the following diagram for the attenuation through an optical fiber (from NASA through wikipedia):

[image: Attenuation through an optical fiber]

You can see that there is a minimum in the losses through the fiber in the IR because both the scattering of light in the fiber and the absorption of light through the fiber are at a minimum here.  Since we'd like to transmit information with the least amount of power, this will dictate our choice of radiation energy (wavelength) for fiber optics.

For free space transmission, it wouldn't be good to use "high" energy radiation such as gamma rays and x-rays because they could be dangerous for peoples health.  Also, the air can scatter high energy radiation (we see a blue sky because of this scattering of blue and violet light for instance).

Comment: I would have thought that the modulation difficulties would be important  for xrays and gamma rays , but it seems http://www.cablinginstall.com/articles/print/volume-3/issue-1/crosstalk-feedback/editorial/bit-rate-and-frequency-in-data-communications.html that you are correct and the losses come first

Comment: That was an informative read.  It certainly shows that there are more factors to consider than what I've said in my simple explanation, even though losses are a primary concern.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, NASA and others are considering the use of X-rays as a communication medium. The difficulty comes in the modulation, and in the fact that X-rays can't be transmitted via wires or fiber. But for vehicles re-entering Earth's atmosphere, X-rays provide a benefit in that they aren't stopped by the ionizing effects of re-entry.
X-rays are also more difficult to focus than visible light. Even though the energy is carried in photons, the higher energy photons don't react in the same way to optical elements.
Lastly, as ionizing radiation, X-rays and gamma rays do have potential health consequences associated with exposure, so any use of these must take into account the safety of those using them, as well as by-standers.

Answer (score 2):

for "wired" transport, you need efficient and compact way to produce, receive, repeat the signal, but also materials able to conduct the given frequency, and materials able to manipulates it (mirrors, lenses...) with the expected effect, with little absorption, and without aging under the energy.

for direct transmission through air you need frequency windows where air is really transparent (real air, including vapor, etc). In addition you can have constraints about the size of the antenna and direct visibility (lower frequencies like sound and radio-waves can a bit turn around obstacle, goes into tunnel and walls. "light" cannot.).

Answer (score 1):

High frequency data transmission is not as practical with limited applications. Range decreasing as frequency increases. Data transmission can use phase modulation to pack more data in narrow bandwidth. This gets harder to do as frequency increases.